# JQuery how to turn this into re useable function

Tags: jquery, function

I have a simple function:

```
var total = 0.00;
$("#basket .txt").each(function() {
  total  += parseFloat($(this).html());
});
$('#total').text('Total: ' + total.toFixed(2));
```

That is used in 3 places on a script.  How do I turn it into a function that can be called in the relevant places a bit like:

```
getTotal();
```

rather than use the "first" code above in each of the 3 places.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 0.00 is unnecessary in javascript, because the language is loosely typed. Just say 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as simple as that:

```
function getTotal() {
  var total = 0.00;
  $("#basket .txt").each(function() {
    total  += parseFloat($(this).html());
  });
  $('#total').text('Total: ' + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: please, edit "getTotol" to "getTotal", and remove ".00" from "var total = 0.00;
"... +1

Comment: +1 -  (Psst Totol isn't a word ;) I would add make sure not to do this: `$(selector).event(function() { getTotal(); });` like I see so often, `$(selector).event(getTotal);` is all you ever need.

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks, but I tried "that" before posting and the rest of the script breaks yet run the code "inside" the other functions and it works perfectly